# Why am I getting invalid syntax on a simple for loop?

Tags: python, loops, syntax

So I've written a simple for loop. It ran earlier, but then I tried to add to the loop, while not even changing the stuff around it. After deleting the stuff I added, it is telling me Syntax Error on the line that creates the for loop.

```
def moving_window(tweet):
    dict = {}
    tweet = tweet.split(' ')
    print(type(tweet[0])
    for i in range(len(tweet)):
        tweet_range = tweet[i:i+3]
        tweet_string = ' '.join(tweet_range)
        dict[tweet_string] = 1
```

```
for i in range(len(tweet)):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas???

Comment: Look closely at the previous line. This sort of typo is common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem is unbalanced parentheses on the previous line:

```
print(type(tweet[0])
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. It kept pointing to other places, so I wasn't even concerned with that line.